# How to mix emission shaders to get gradient effect

Tags: node-editor

I'm trying to get the result like the globe which illuminates more than 2 colours. I have 2 examples, one with ColorRamp and one with 2 emission shaders, but the colour variations are not visible only one appears on the plane mesh. I cant figure out the Node configuration to get the result.

[image]

Comment: Please note there are 2-D simple spherical gradient textures which can be used to apply color.  Also note that distance from a give  point can be computed.  c squared = a squared + b squared.  This math can be used to compute a gradient.

Comment: OK thanks for your reply, but I'd like to see the possibility of mixing 2 emission shaders using nodes if its possible.

Comment: Two emission shaders are not necessary since it is the color of the emission that may be more important to you.  You should do it your way of course.

Comment: Please note there are 2-D simple spherical gradient textures which can be used to apply color.  Also note that distance from a given  point can be computed.  c squared = a squared + b squared.  This math can be used to compute a gradient. Also the geometric [normal] can be used to compute angle from a target normal.  Perhaps you can change your nodes to use that information or state that you want do not want to change your nodes.  Can you place a spherical light source inside a spherical mesh?  You can also texture paint on the sphere.  I do not know which of these are acceptable to you.

Comment: So the distance from a given point may determine what combination of 2 colors to use. 40% of this and 60% of that.  Of course the color ramp node is available to you for many colors .. 32??  The geometry node as well.

Comment: One the 1st version I think you also need a gradient texture before the color ramp - possibly a mapping node as well.

On the 2nd version with two emission shaders combined with the mix - have you tried adding a Fresnel into the factor of the mix shader to control the center vs the edge color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe try something like this. Since you're already using a globe (sphere), you can get a good gradient by mixing the Emission colors using a Fresnel as a mix factor:

[image: GlowGradient1]

If you want a "glassy" globe, you can mix the result with a Glass Shader, using the same Fresnel as a mix factor for that too:

[image: GlowGradient2]

Comment: Thats what I was after, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate some type of mask to feed into your color ramp.  You can then use it to define the factor of a number of nodes.  Here are a couple of examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can, of course, experiment and find all kinds of combinations.